# Dynamic Templates and Jquery Steps

Tags: meteor

I'm working to create a form wizard with jQuery steps. From step 1 to step 2 I need to be able to determine which template is loaded depending on the selection in step 1. I have this template. I would like a different template to be rendered as a session variable changes.

```
<template name = "selectFrame">
    <div class = "container">
         <div class = "frameCarousel">
             {{> Template.dynamic template=active data=this}}
         </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Each of the internal templates look like this template below.

```
<template name = "artLineFrame">
    {{#each artLineFrames}}
    <div class = "thumbnail">
       <div class = "something">
            <img data-src = "{{source}}" alt = "placeholder" class = "img-circle">
            <h2>{{name}}</h2>
            <p>{{description}}</p>
            <button type = "button" id = "{{tag}}" class = "btn btn-primary">Select</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</template>
<template name = "classicFrame">
    {{#each classicFrames}}
    <div class = "thumbnail">
        <div class = "something">
            <img data-src = "{{source}}" alt = "placeholder" class = "img-circle">
            <h2>{{name}}</h2>
            <p>{{description}}</p>
            <button type = "button" id = "{{alt}}" class = "btn btn-primary">Select</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</template>
<template name = "versionsFrame">
    {{#each versionsFrames}}
    <div class = "thumbnail">
        <div class = "something">
            <img data-src = "{{source}}" alt = "placeholder" class = "img-circle">
            <h2>{{name}}</h2>
            <p>{{description}}</p>
            <button type = "button" id = "{{alt}}" class = "btn btn-primary">Select</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</template>
<template name = "myHarmonyFrame">
    {{#each myHarmonyFrames}}
    <div class = "thumbnail">
        <div class = "something">
            <img data-src = "{{source}}" alt = "placeholder" class = "img-circle">
            <h2>{{name}}</h2>
            <p>{{description}}</p>
            <button type = "button" id = "{{tag}}" class = "btn btn-primary">Select</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Active is a function that gets the value of the session variable and returns the name of the appropriate template.

```
Template.selectFrame.created = function() {
this.selectFrame = new ReactiveVar(null);

this.autorun(function(){
    var templateName = Session.get('board');
    console.log('##' + templateName);
    Template.instance().selectFrame.set(templateName);

})
Tracker.flush();
}
Template.selectFrame.helpers({
'active' : function() {
    var dynamicName = Template.instance().selectFrame.get();
    return dynamicName;
}
})
```

The value of board, the session variable that determines which template will render, changes as it should but the only template that ever renders is the template that the default value of board is set too. Can anyone offer some help or some edits I need to make.

Comment: I am experiencing this issue as well. I can only guess that it's something with JQuery Steps that is breaking our spacebar templating. Only variables on the first "step" are updated reactively; nothing else is updated, even when I manually call Session.set() somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into a similar problem.

Instead of using the session variable directly, I created a ReactiveVar and used that instead in the helper.

(to get access to ReactiveVar add it to your project with: *meteor add reactive-var* )

First I created a reactive variable to store the name of the template I wanted it to dynamically change to within Template.name.created:

```
this.templateName = new ReactiveVar(null);
```

then I created an autorun within the Template.name.rendered function to change this value to whatever the session variable was changed to:

```
this.autorun(function(){
    var templateName = Session.get("template_name");
    Template.instance().templateName.set(templateName);
})
```

And finally I changed the template helper to get the template name from the reactive variable:

```
dynamic_template: function(){
    var dynamicName = Template.instance().templateName.get();
    return dynamicName;
}
```

I hope this approach works for your particular case.

Comment: I still can't seem to get it to work. Take a look at the updated code if you have a second

Comment: I looked at my code and it seems that the autorun was defined in the Template.name.rendered function, not the created one.  Sorry for that, I'll edit my answer as necessary.

Comment: not working for me. I'm not sure. When I changed the created to rendered it says that template.instance().templateName.get() is not an object. I added a console.log after the rendered function and the function never gets called. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing your code example. You use template.name multiple times but its not clear to me which of them match up with the others. Or are they all supposed to be the same?

Comment: yes, the use of names is a bit confusing. template.instance() should be Template.instance().